# Documenting node.js using doxygen

Tags: javascript, node.js, doxygen

I always document my C projects using Doxygen.

I started working with NodeJs and when I tried to document *.js* files, there was no output. I searched the web but couldn't find any explanations about why Doxygen behaved this way.

Can I document NodeJs code using Doxygen? If not, I would like to know if there are any good documentation tools similar to Doxygen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen has a limited support of javascript. Something similar to it that is cannonical to JavaScript would be [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app).

@albert noted in the comments, that there was a small issue with the default setting of the default patterns. A proposed patch has been sent to github ([pull request 383](http://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/383)) with title "Make list of default extensions consistent with language mapping list".

Comment: doxygen does support, in a limited way, javascript. There was a small issue with the default setting of the default patterns. A proposed patch as been send to github (pull request 383, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/383) with title "Make list of default extensions consistent with language mapping list"

Comment: @albert, thank you, I've updated the post to reflect this